# Noderunner reduce ram usage for specific component

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, farm-admin

Is it possible to reduce the RAM usage of a specific component of SP search service? I know that it is a possibility to use this PowerShell command:

```
Set-SPEnterpriseSearchService -PerformanceLevel Reduced
```

and then change the value of memory limit in the config file for noderunner, but there is only one config file where the limit can be set. I want, for example, the crawl component of noderunner memory limit to be set to 1500MB and for query processing component the limit to be set to 1000MB.

Is this somehow possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the config value is absolutely unsupported. In addition, it will generally lead to noderunning crashes.

Beyond setting the perf level to Reduced, there is nothing you can do to 'control' memory. The answer is simple: add more RAM.